# What matrix should I multiply to a 2*2 and 3*3 matrices to make a 3*2 matrix?

Tags: matrices

All daylong I'm thinking about this problem but still nothing!

[image: image1]

It has made me confused that What matrix should I multiply to a 2*2 (B) and 3*3 (A) matrices to make a 3*2 (C) matrix. What would be M matrix?

Comment: C is a 3x2 matrix. 3 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: @TroyG Oops. Thanks.

Comment: Suppose $M$ has $r$ rows and $c$ columns. Since $AM$ exists, $r$ is the number of columns in $A$, i.e. $3$. Since $MB$ exists, $c$ is the number of rows in $B$, i.e. 2. SInce $M$ has 6 components, you could find $M$ by solving 6 simultaneous linear equations in 6 unknowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test $M=A^{-1}BC^{-1}.$

(after having checked that $A$ and $B$ are invertible)

Comment: Thank you so much!, going to test it.